# R print map with ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

this is a reproducible peace of code
and if you run it you would see that it prints a map with two blueish dots.. I would like to add as a separe point (different style,color and shape) the stationaryPoint. I tried having a second geom_point but unfortunately this just returns me a warning.
can you please help me?
Regards
Alex

```
require("ggplot2")
require("ggmap")
jet.colors <- colorRampPalette(c("#00007F", "red", "#007FFF", "yellow", "#7FFF7F", "cyan", "#FF7F00", "blue", "#7F0000"))
bbox<-c(-0.1505833, 51.5117722, -0.1363361, 51.5188167)
mp <- get_stamenmap(bbox, maptype = "toner", zoom = 16)


# prepare data points to plot
# First Set
dfE<-data.frame(c(-0.1456250,-0.1442639),c(51.51476,51.51492),c(0.018878676,0.111847050))
names(dfE) <- c("Longitude", "Latitude", "Error")

# Second Set
stationaryPoint<-data.frame(0.1422361,51.51516)
names(stationaryPoint) <- c("Longitude", "Latitude")

ggmap(mp, darken = 0) + geom_point(aes(Longitude, Latitude, colour =Error), data = dfE, size = 10)+geom_point(aes(Longitude,Latitude),data=stationaryPoint)
```

Answer (score 3):

use

```
stationaryPoint<-data.frame(-0.1422361,51.51516)
```

instead of

```
stationaryPoint<-data.frame(0.1422361,51.51516)
```

The original point was outside the map boundary. ggplot2 converts coordinates outside the limits into `NA`. Hence the warning.